# wcf session authentication

Tags: wcf, load-balancing

I'm currently building a game that uses a client/server model.  I'd like the server side to be a WCF service.  The client will be silverlight or flash.  What  need to solve is session authentication.  A user needs to log into the game, be authenticated via the service and hopefully establish a "session." I need to make sure that you can't send commands to the server without being authenticated.  Authentication on the server side will be tied to a SQL database.  I should also mention that it needs to be a duplex connection.

Related to this question, what about load balancing?  If the service runs on multiple machines and is load balanced with the NLB service and I store those connection references, how would I get a reference to a client connected to a different machine in the same cluster?